# How to call a other database function in a stored procedure returning select cursor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Here I have two data bases, DB1 and DB2. From DB2 procedure I want to call a function of DB1 like below

```
OPEN cur FOR 
  SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_DATE,'DD MM YYYY') as DATE_UTC,
        TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_DATE,'HH24:MI:SS') as TIME_UTC,
        IP_ADDRESS,
        (TRANSACTION_DATE + (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - SYSTIMESTAMP)) as Local_Time,
        ID,
        (select DB1.GET_NAME(12) from dual) as TEST_NAME;
```

When I call it from Oracle SQL worksheet, it is working; but when we call it in a cursor, it is not working.

I tried below both ways in that returning cursor:

1. `(select DB1.GET_NAME(12) from dual) as TEST_NAME;`
2. `(DB1.GET_NAME(12)) as TEST_NAME;`

Any one please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Any error? If so, which one? Also, are you sure that those are "databases" and not "schemas"? Because, you certainly can't reference another **database** object as you did (you'd need a database link), but - from another **schema**, yes. Besides, did you grant privileges from DB1 to DB2 **directly** (i.e. not via role)? If not, you should have.

Comment: @Littlefoot Not working means the cursor returning empty data in test_name column but when i call in DB2 sql work sheet it is returning value